# how to run a javascript function loaded using jquery .load

Tags: jquery

i googled and searched here to but unable to figure it out my script is not working

i'm loading a html file using .load function file loaded successfully but javascirpt in is not working when i view that file in browser all works..

below function is loading html file

```
function loadPage(page, pageElement) {

$(pageElement).load('pages/page' + page + '.html');

//loadRegions(page, pageElement);}
```

this is the function in ajax loaded html file

`addLoadEvent(load1);`

script is generated by pdftohtml script that generate canvas... i can't attach it to any event like click .. can it work as it is...

**pdftohtml generate script**

```
function adjustCharSpacing(el,actualWidth) {
    var rawWidth=el.offsetWidth;
    if(actualWidth>20 & rawWidth!=actualWidth && actualWidth>rawWidth){
        var spacing= 0;
        var s=spacing+'px';
        el.style.charSpacing = s;
        rawWidth=el.offsetWidth;

        var diff=rawWidth-actualWidth;
        if(diff20 && actualWidth>rawWidth && rawWidth!=actualWidth & el.textContent.search(' ') > -1){
        var spacing= 0;
        var s=spacing+'px';
        el.style.wordSpacing = s;
        rawWidth=el.offsetWidth;

        var diff=rawWidth-actualWidth;
        if(diff12 & rawWidth>5 & rawWidth!=actualWidth){
        if(rawWidth>actualWidth){
            while (rawWidth>actualWidth & lastRawWidth!=rawWidth){
                pixelSize--;
                el.style.fontSize = pixelSize+'px';
                lastRawWidth=rawWidth;
                rawWidth=el.offsetWidth;
            }
            var lastDiff=lastRawWidth-actualWidth;
            var nextDiff=actualWidth-rawWidth;
            if(lastDiff5)
            el.style.fontSize = pixelSize+'px';
        else
            el.style.fontSize = rawFontSize+'px';

        if(pixelSize!=el.style.fontSize){
            adjustCharSpacing(el,actualWidth);
            adjustWordSpacing(el,actualWidth);
        }

    }
}

var pdf;
function M(a,b){pdf.moveTo(a,b);}
function L(a,b){pdf.lineTo(a,b);}
function C(a,b,c,d,e,f){pdf.bezierCurveTo(a,b,c,d,e,f);}
function Q(a,b,c,d){pdf.quadraticCurveTo(a,b,c,d);}
function BP(){pdf.beginPath();}
function CP(){pdf.closePath();}
function LW(a){pdf.lineWidth=a;}
function LC(a){pdf.lineCap=a;}
function LJ(a){pdf.lineJoin=a;}
function ML(a){pdf.miterLimit=a;}
function SS(a){pdf.strokeStyle=a;}
function ST(){pdf.stroke();}
function GA(a){pdf.globalAlpha=a;}
function FS(a){pdf.fillStyle=a;}
function FI(){pdf.fill();}
function CL(){pdf.clip();}
function SV(){pdf.save();}
function RS(){pdf.restore();}

var loaded1 = false;
var assetsLoaded1 = 0;
var assetCount1 = 20;
var images1 = new Array();
var imageCount1 = 20;
function load1(){
    if (!loaded1) {
        loaded1=true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("l1")[0].innerHTML = "Loading Assets...";
        for (var i = 1; i
```

Answer (score 1):

use the callback function of `load()` method:

```
$(pageElement).load('pages/page' + page + '.html',function(){
    $('#myCanvas').on('click',function(){alert('canvas clicked');});
});
```

Or use delegation, e.g:

```
$(document.body).on('click','myCanvas', function(){
    alert('canvas clicked');
});
```

Comment: Might want to show actually calling the `addLoadEvent` function.

Comment: how this will call addLoadEvent(load1) load1 is function specific to each html file i will be loading hundred of html files... using loadPage function ...

Comment: i want it without clicking anywhere or element ... i want to call function loadPage and function inside ajax loaded html can work auto ?

Comment: @roasted i added the script that is generated by pdftohtml files that i'm loading .. and i used your script but still its not working for me .. i don't know all functions in ajax loade files executed or not ..

Comment: if i run the file from same tab and go back to page that is loading it using ajax it works ...than i refresh i stops working why its happening ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the load callback function (first example) to call your function?

Comment: i haven't time to debug your website, thx for your comprehension

Comment: @roasted i got the issue can you please tell me how i can call this function addLoadEvent(load1); paramater is also function ( load1) if i run only load1 directly it works...